# System clock in Docker (MacOS) jumps back in time

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos, clock

I am running `Postgres` in `Docker` on `MacOS`. My application relies on `Postgres` generating timestamps rapidly one after another. I encountered some issues, which turned out to be due to `Postgres` generating timestamps in the past. E.g. the following were created in the order shown, using the `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()` function in `Postgres`:

Timestamp 1: `2023-10-29 16:02:06.887574+00`
Timestamp 2: `2023-10-29 16:02:06.872373+00`
Timestamp 3: `2023-10-29 16:02:06.891193+00`

But the timestamps are out of order: `Timestamp 2` < `Timestamp 1` < `Timestamp 3`.

This would happen seemingly random (every few thousand requests to the db server).

However, the above issue does not occur, when using a `Postgres` server running locally (not in `Docker`).

This makes me believe that `Docker` is here to blame. It appears as if the system clock used by `Docker` (which is used by the `Postgres Docker Container` to generate timestamps) sometimes shifts back in time. I found the following article on the [Docker blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/addressing-time-drift-in-docker-desktop-for-mac/), which is suggesting that this "jump back in time" indeed does happen, but that the "VM clock" should always be running slower than the "system clock", meaning that this should never result in an actual jump back in time... But for me the "VM clock" seems to be running faster, as I am seeing this jump back in time.

This [github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4347), seems to be running into the same problem as me, but it got closed due to being stale.

My question thus is, is my suspicion above correct that the issue I'm facing is due to a "jump back in time"? Or might there be something else going on?

The below `Node.js` code snippet, when run long enough, will trigger the issue I'm facing:

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');

const test = async () => {
  const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'postgres',
  });

  await client.connect();

  let prevClockTimestamp;
  let iteration = 0;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
  while (true) {
    const {
      rows: [{ clockTimestamp }],
    } = await client.query(
      'SELECT CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()::text AS "clockTimestamp"'
    );

    if (clockTimestamp < prevClockTimestamp) {
      console.log(clockTimestamp, prevClockTimestamp);
      await client.end();
      throw new Error('Gotcha...');
    }

    prevClockTimestamp = clockTimestamp;
    iteration += 1;

    if (iteration % 1000 === 0) {
      console.log(iteration);
    }
  }
};

test();
```

Node version is `v18.18.2`
Docker Desktop version is `4.15.0 (93002)`
Postgres version is `16.0` (runs in Docker)
MacOS version is `10.15.7`

Comment: Reading the [postgres source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/5ba4cc309095eb1a947961e66b9c5156efc8ffca/src/backend/utils/adt/timestamp.c#L1615), it would appear that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is implemented in terms of gettimeofday(), which is a non-monotonic clock, so that seems plausible.

Comment: What are your requirements? Would it be good enough to have a clock that is guaranteed to not go backwards during a transaction?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77375142/6464308). Did you check if the problem is caused by threading issues and disappears if you don't use `await`, as recommended in a comment there?

Comment: @NickODell Thank you for your comments. Regarding the requirements: it must be monotonic and it must be "current time" not "(start of) transaction time"